# Google Play Services and ARM Translation on Genymotion 2.3.0

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services, genymotion

I have tried all the possible available online solutions to install Google Play services and ARM translation v1.1 on my Genymotion 2.3.0 version with Android Studio but I am not able to flash the downloaded zip. I have also tried multiple emulators 4.2.2 and 4.4.4 Android release version Genymotion devices. I tried the instructions mentioned at the following link :

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952%5d

Specifically I am stuck at the point It should say "File transfer in progress", once it asks you to flash it click "OK". Since the emulator never asks me to flash the ARM translation file but simply copies it to the `/sdcard/download`.

I am basically trying to start a login activity with Google Plus. I got the sample code from [here](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android). I also tried using the default login activity that is provided but Android Studio but it does not seem to work.

FYI I have a MacBook Pro and recently upgraded my OS to OS X Yosemite.

Comment: The problem might be a corrupt download, it will only offer to flash a zip if it detects it as a flashable zip

Comment: @Machinarius Thanks much for your reply. I have tried multiple mirrors for the ARM translation provided at the link but none of them is getting flashed ..

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve this myself. This is an issue with Mac only. Following are the errors and there solution :

- Error 1. Files copied to /sdcard/downloads
  Solution - uncheck the Safri->preferences->general->open "safe" files after downloading. 
  Why : Safari unzips the downloaded file which renders it useless to be flashed onto Genymotion.
- Error 2: Failed to Deploy file
  Solution - restart your Macbook (not your Genymotion). This seems to be an issue when you put the macbook to sleep with Genymotion Emulator in ON state. 
  Why : There seems to be some issue with Genymotion and Android Studio connection after Macbook mwake-up from Sleep state.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that my genymotion instances seem to corrupt the GL state once my macbook is suspended

Comment: for me, the installation of [VirtualBox extensions](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.10/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-5.0.10-104061.vbox-extpack) helped. I did it with the following commands:  
`$ brew cask install virtualbox`  
`$ brew install Caskroom/cask/virtualbox-extension-pack`